# Why does my jquery modal stop working after full page ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ive discovered that I have an issue with the jQuery dialog (using jquery 1.3 , pretty old but I cannot update it).

When I do

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "${Request.context}/info/" + userId,
  success: function(response) {
    $("#userInfo").html(response);
  }
});

$("#divUserInfo").dialog('open');
}
```

where

```
$('#divUserInfo').dialog({
  width: 700,
  height: 250,
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  title: "User Info",
  resizable: false
});
```

The dialog itself works fine, opens everytime when it has no content or when I do `$("#userInfo").html("any string possible");`

But when I load the entire page of the ajax response, I see no error on my console but I cannot re-open the dialog. Is there any way I can avoid that happening? should I reload the DOM or something similar? or extract the body of the response?

Comment: Is `#divUserInfo` inside `#userInfo`?  If so, when you replace the DOM you're overwriting the `.dialog()` binding.

Comment: no, userInfo is inside divUserInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-initialize dialog plugin after replacing DOM with ajax response, so that it works for updated DOM elements as well

**Try this:**

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "${Request.context}/info/" + userId,
  success: function(response) {
    $("#userInfo").html(response);
    $('#divUserInfo').dialog({
      width: 700,
      height: 250,
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      title: "User Info",
      resizable: false
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: it opens it correctly! but..... an instant after it opens the dialog hides all the content, any idea why?

Comment: it depends upon the response html, might be display none content is there, try to inspect content inside the dialog box and see which particular div has display none property, if you can provide the link to test then i can help you in this more.

Comment: I changed the part of define the dialog after the response function and worked fine, thanks!